# Adding a Button on a View

Tags: java, android, user-interface

I am going nuts over this.

I did not find any working solution (tried a few from stackoverflow)

Scenario (this is an actual screenshot what is already done):

[image]

I have a Activity that has a View as his Attribute.

This view adds another view via View.addView(myView).

I now want to add a Button to myView (to be specific: after MotionEvent.ACTION_UP the button should appear in the right lower corner (this will start the robot to drive the track))

Here is a shortcut of my code:

```
public class ModeRouting extends View {
public ModeRouting(Context context) {
    super(context);
Button asuroStartButton = new Button(context) //does not work
}

@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    int actionevent = event.getAction();
    if (actionevent == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP
            || actionevent == MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL) {
asuroStartButton.visible=true;
view.add(asuroStartButton);
    }
    return true;
}
}
```

and my Activity:

```
//in constructor
contentView = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.content);
onClickListenerFacade(routingMode, route);

//this removes all views from stack and places the new one on the view
private void onClickListenerFacade(View v, final View target) {
    v.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            contentView.removeAllViews();
            contentView.setBackgroundColor(0xff000000);
            contentView.addView(target);
            modeSelectorAnimation();
        }
    });
}
```

I tried to create a button in my mainactivity.xml  and instantiate in my mainactivity.

I am missing some point in here but i am not sure which.

Since my view is purely dynamic (no layout.xml) i dont think i should use a layout.xml (maybe thats my mind-blockage) but instead set the button attributes dynamically too.

Any hint is appreciated!

Comment: So what's the question?

Comment: I cannot instantiate a button nor can i add one.
do i need an static xml to add a button and where do i need to instantiate (mainactivity?). wont a static xml override/destroy the dynamic content (for example using setContentView(R.layout.xy) would destroy my track?)

Comment: You dont need a static xml for a button. You could use something like : Button sampleButton = new Button(context);

Comment: bloody hell. not sure what i did wrong but now it just works by doing like you said. thank you very much. Edit: i can instantiate but i dont have an this.addObject/addView function. How can i add it to the view after this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to extend ViewGroup rather than just a View (LinearLayout, RelativeLayout, FrameLayout, etc) - they handle child views for you.

Comment: thank you. now i got the this.addView(button) feature.
the only problem is that the button wont appear.
i did set width/heigth 200,200 and visibility=true, furthermore bringtofront(). still not visible. gonna continue trying

Comment: What did you extend? You most likely want to extend RelativeLayout. In which case you'll want to call setLayoutParams() passing a RelativeLayout.LayoutParams specifying the location you want the view to be at.

Comment: Oh thats the problem. i extended from ViewGroup. Gonna fix that tomorrow, thank you

Answer (score 0):

I think maybe you need to refresh the whole view/activity. Try to do this in the onResume methode, maybe this helps. But as you don't use a layout.xml, I'm not sure if this helps you much..

```
@Override
protected void onResume(){
super.onResume();
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}
```

Comment: thanks for your effort but i don't think this was helpful. using your suggestion would be the same as removing the view from my activity.